# What happens to local files when I update my app?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have an application for iOS and Android, but I have never released any updates, that is, it is at version 1. I would like to know if when I release the update (version 2) what will happen with the local files of the app, in the following situations:

1. An app local file that was not in version 1, was added in version 2
   (Ex: an image that was added)
2. An app local file in version 1, has been removed in version 2 (Ex:
   an image that has been removed, will it be deleted or will nothing
   happen to it?)
3. An app local file contained in the version 1 package, has been
   changed in version 2 (Ex: an image that has been changed)
4. An app local file contained in version 1 and 2 (exactly the same
   file), was changed by the app in version 1 at runtime, when it is
   updated to version 2, will it return to the original? (Ex: a
   database that existed in version 1, also exists in version 2, but
   since it was changed during use in version 1, will it be replaced by
   the database contained in version 2 or will it keep the changes from
   version 1?)
5. An app local file contained in version 1, was changed at runtime by
   version 1, but it was also changed in version 2 (Ex: a database that
   existed in version 1 was changed at runtime by version 1, but it was
   redone in version 2)

@edit
My app was made in Delphi (firemonkey)

Comment: I did not read your long story but in general nothing happens with the apps files if it is updated. You can test that easily every time you compile and upload your app with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

An app on iOS is distributed as a bundle (essentially a zip file). The bundle is read-only; it cannot be changed at runtime. When an app is upgraded on iOS the entire bundle is replaced.

An app can copy files from the bundle and save them to the read/write sandbox file system, but you need to write code to do this explicitly.

For your cases:

1. The additional file will be in the bundle. If you want this file on local storage you need to copy it via code.
2. The file will no longer be present in the bundle. Any local copy that was made by your previous version will remain.
3. The updated file will be in the bundle. Any local copy that was made by your previous version will remain and won't be changed.
4. The app cannot have made changes to files in the bundle, it can only have copied the file from the bundle to local storage before modifying it, so this is essentially case 3.
5. Again this is basically case 3.

Things may be different on Android.

Answer (score 0):

My app was made in Delphi (firemonkey), I didn't mention it because I thought that replacing local files would be done by the AppStore and PlayStore in the update. But thanks to [Paulw11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60585189/2614619) response, I was able to find out that it was Delphi himself who is responsible for this replacement, and contains a configurable property in each file called ["Overwrite"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Deployment_Manager#Deployment_Manager_Fields).